# Oracle conditional order by

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

I am trying to get a list of users and the departments they are apart of from a database.  I would like to order by users asc where they have no departments first and then the rest of the users asc.  Below is my current sql statement that gives me a list of users asc then order by deptCode asc:

```
SELECT
  userDepts.ID,
  users.ID AS USER_ID,                            
  userDepts.DEPT_CODE,
  users.USERNAME                                     
  FROM SCRIPTS.TB_FRSCHL_USER_DEPTS userDepts
  FULL OUTER JOIN SCRIPTS.TB_FRSCHL_USERS users ON (users.ID = userDepts.USER_ID)
  ORDER BY users.USERNAME ASC, DEPT_CODE ASC
```

An example of my results is below:

```
ID   | USER_ID | DEPT_CODE | USERNAME
null |   1234  |    null   |      adam.doe
null |   2341  |    null   |      ana.jane
9876 |   3412  |    cpsc   |      john.doe
4567 |   4987  |    crim   |      mike.smith
null |   4123  |    null   |      test.user
```

I would like it to look like this below:

```
 ID   | USER_ID | DEPT_CODE | USERNAME
null |   1234  |    null   |      adam.doe
null |   2341  |    null   |      ana.jane
null |   4123  |    null   |      test.user
9876 |   3412  |    cpsc   |      john.doe
4567 |   4987  |    crim   |      mike.smith
```

I've tried using CASE in the order by but I've had no luck thus far.  Is what I want possible with sql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like below

```
SELECT
  userDepts.ID,
  users.ID AS USER_ID,                            
  userDepts.DEPT_CODE,
  users.USERNAME                                     
  FROM SCRIPTS.TB_FRSCHL_USER_DEPTS userDepts
  FULL OUTER JOIN SCRIPTS.TB_FRSCHL_USERS users ON (users.ID = userDepts.USER_ID)
  ORDER BY case when userDepts.ID is null then 1 else 2 end , users.ID
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  Quick question what does the 1 and 2 mean and what is users.Id at the end for?

Comment: @crmckain when id will get null it will consider as 1 and rest is 2 so it will make customize order

Comment: so if userDepts.ID is null then put those first then and 2 is the rest of the users.  And the ", users.ID" at the end is just included in that

Comment: @crmckain  end is for closing of case when and users.id is ordering as it is

Comment: I had to wait 10 minutes for some reason before it would let me mark the answer as correct.